# Moisture detection not resetting

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, detection

I have a friend setting up an irrigation system at his house. He is telling me it won't detect moisture after the first run-through, regardless of whether there is moisture or not. In his own words:

> "I’m trying to figure out how to make my program restarts the detection process. Like say my sensor is in soil and it detects water then after a certain period I need it to run again. My problems is that when I run it again and it’s sitting in a cup of water, it’s doesn’t detect the water. I read something about maybe checking the state of the sensor but I couldn’t get anywhere.
> Also would I would the delay function to continuously run it in intervals."

He sent me his code today, and I would like to help him, although I am new to Python. Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#GPIO SETUP
channel = 20
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.IN)

def callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(channel)==0:
        print (" Water Detected!")
    else:
        print ( 'NO Water Detected!')

GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime=300)  # let us know when the pin goes HIGH or LOW
GPIO.add_event_callback(channel, callback)  # assign function to GPIO PIN, Run function on change

# infinite loop
while True:
    time.sleep(1)


import RPi.GPIO as GPIO    # Import Raspberry Pi GPIO library
from time import sleep     # Import the sleep function from the time module
GPIO.setwarnings(False)    # Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)   # Use physical pin numbering
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)   # Set pin 8 to be an outputpin and set initial value to low (off)

while True: # Run forever
    GPIO.output(3, GPIO.HIGH) # Turn on
    sleep(1)                  # Sleep for 1 second
    GPIO.output(3, GPIO.LOW)  # Turn off
    sleep(1)                  # Sleep for 1 second
```

Comment: It looks like two different pieces of code are present in your question. If that isn't a posting mistake, then it will never get beyond the first infinite loop. If it is two separate scripts, what is the significance of each?

Comment: This was a friends code, and I said something to him about that. It's appearing like he may have "Frankenstein-ed" this to make it work. I redirected him to some documentation for his actual model, but I am waiting to hear back. He is less than savvy about the research end, so I am simply trying to bridge the gap so he can get some help. I appreciate you reaching out, and I will forward your message to him.

Comment: This question appears to have been abandoned, so voting to close as "typo" for now.